# Changing Cell color

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the color in a Cell

```
MyColour = Range("A" & myRow).Cells.Interior.Color  ' <<< THIS line doesn't work !

Range("A" & myRow).Cells.Interior.Color = Range("A" & myRow-3).Cells.Interior.Color
```

and then later change it back again.

```
Range("A" & myRow).Cells.Interior.Color = MyColour
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try `Range("A" & myRow).Interior.Color`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

- Use of `.Cells`

**Here:**

```
MyColour = Range("A" & myRow).Interior.Color

Range("A" & myRow).Interior.Color = Range("A" & myRow - 3).Interior.Color

Range("A" & myRow).Interior.Color = MyColour
```